# How to send individual data to subcriber in Mailchimp?

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

I want to send individual coupon code for every individual subscriber how can i send mail through Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can send the individual email data to the subscribers  [Find this tutorial to send through add a new field](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/using/use-merge-tags-to-send-personalized-files)